# Reacting ZnSO4 with KCl

Tags: reaction-mechanism, aqueous-solution, solubility

I'm considering the following reaction:

$\ce{ZnSO4} + 2 \ce{KCl} \ce{->} \ce{ZnCl2} + \ce{K2SO4}$

The high solubility of $\ce{ZnCl2}$ would favour the $\ce{ZnSO4}$ & $\ce{KCl}$ direction of the reaction, but I'm wondering if I could turn this around by making the reaction occur in a flow of boiling hot water.

The idea would be to subject (initially dry) $\ce{ZnSO4}$ & $\ce{KCl}$ stationary phase to a flow of water in the 80-100°C range. The comparative solubility of $\ce{ZnCl2}$ at this temperature being high, I'm wondering if it being comparatively flushed away more than the other species could help drive the reaction forwards in the opposite direction?

I wouldn't get pure $\ce{ZnCl2}$ of course but I'd be happy if I could get a 90% $\ce{ZnCl2}$ solution from dry $\ce{ZnSO4}$ & $\ce{KCl}$.

Comment: There is no reaction, nor is there a need for one. A solution of ZnSO4 and KCl is **the same** as solution of ZnCl2 and K2SO4.

Comment: Is it not called a double-replacement reaction?

Comment: It would be, if some of the participating salts were insoluble. That's not the case, though.

Comment: If one of the salts can be otherwise partly isolated from the reaction medium, is it not somewhat equivalent to one being insoluble? Could the "reaction" proceed by one of the products being comparatively carried away many times more than the reagents combined?

Comment: It is _lower_, not higher solubility, that might separate one of the products from the reaction mixture and thus drive the reaction that way. With all four salts rather well-soluble, we're out of luck.

Comment: Yes, I understand that (if the solvent is stationary). But would it not change if the solvent was limited and moving across a stationary, mostly undissolved mix of the salts?

Comment: That would be a setting too exotic to tell for sure.

Comment: Would you even get pure zinc sulfate and potassium chloride again if you dissolve them both in water and then boil them off?  I'm guessing since zinc chloride is more soluble, there would be more zinc sulfate that forms though...

Comment: @chemN00b Of course, but this can only happen to the limit of existing sulphate ions, which as you correctly write are less soluble than chloride ions and thus would only be a minor part of the "washed-out" solution. And they can actually be somewhat further separated by the drying process you refer to (initial precipitate would be richer in sulphate ions and later precipitate richer in chloride and potassium ions).